# How to solve an integral with functional bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If I have the following:

$\int\limits_{g(b)}^{f(a)} {3c^2dc} $

when solved and expanded does it equal the following:

${(f(a))^3} - {(g(b))^3}$

Or does it use some type of chain rule?

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It doesn’t use chain rule, you just integrate like normal and plug in the upper and lower bounds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(a)$ and $g(b)$ are just numbers (depending of $a$ and $b$ but no matter), so you can integrate as if the bounds were constant :

$$\int_{g(b)}^{f(a)} 3c^2 \mathrm{dc} = [c^3]_{g(b)}^{f(a)} = (f(a))^3-(g(b))^3$$

Comment: that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{g(b)}^{f(a)}3c^2dc=\left[c^3\right]_{g(b)}^{f(a)}=f^3(a)-g^3(b)$$ so yes you are correct